# Import Data to Google Form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, import

I have a Google Form that is going to ask users a number of questions about a certain service they can choose from a drop down question. Is it possible to import data from a linked Google Sheet into the form based on the answer to this drop down question, so the user can see the data in the form as they fill it out?

For example, the user chooses the 'Catering' Service from the drop down question. I would like the form to pull across data from the Google Sheet to show how much income/expenditure the 'Catering' service has shown in the past 30 days, so they can use this information to inform their subsequent answers in the form.

Unfortunately, this cannot be done manually as the Google Sheet is updated daily via a script and I would like the form to display the latest data.

If this is not possible in Google Forms, is there a webform service that does provide such functionality?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this cannot be done. Everything must be set in the form itself.

Comment: HI and welcome to WebApps. How often as users completing this form? For example, you said that the spreadsheet 'Catering' figures are updated every day; well, there's nothing to stop you uploading those figures to the form every day.

Comment: @Tedinoz unfortunately, manual updating is not really feasible given the breadth of services covered and the required time investment. Having asked this question in the google forums it looks like the add-on 'Form Ranger' may be able to do this.

Comment: Glad you have a solution in sight. Just for clarification, I wasn’t suggesting “manual” updating. You would update the data from the spreadsheet to the Form by a script using a time-driven trigger. Is that easier/harder to do compared to an add-on, I don’t know. But it is an option. Anyway, I suggest that you turn your comment  into an answer (I.e. answer you own question). It may help someone in the future.